# how to find the string from the line in bash?

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have string as below,

```
May 29 01:30:15 apps1 docker/[a:vjwdrze2e3qxrf5eck4s3yv:a][u:jack:u][5425]: 05:30:15.693 INFO  [mockAppThread:21] app.js - API Mock App Server started successfully on 0.0.0.0 with port 7001.
```

As an output, I want only timestamp and the error message.

```
May 29 01:30:15 API Mock App Server started successfully on 0.0.0.0 with port 7001.
```

I can get the timestamp by awk command as below.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

I can get the message as below,

```
cut -d "-" -f2
```

How can I get both in a single command? Is there any simplified way to get it?

Comment: If your string in `str` always has `"apps1"` and `"- API"` in the same place (and no other `'-'` in between), you can simply do `echo ${str/[ ]apps1*[-]/}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{sub(/ apps1.*app\.js/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk -F" app.js - " '{sub(/ apps1.*/,"",$1);print $1,$2}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** As per Subeh's suggestion in comments adding 1 more solution now too.

```
awk -F'apps1|app.js -' '{ print $1 $3 }' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice double `awk` answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is there a way we can add INFO as well in between

Comment: you can even add both conditions to the delimiter like `awk -F'apps1|app.js -' '{ print $1, $3 }'`

Comment: @BhavikJoshi, if you want to add `INFO` between time and api strings then change `print $1,$2` to `print $1,"INFO",$2` in my 2nd solution then. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: @Subbeh, cool buddy, added 3rd solution now in my post too, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `perl` or `sed` to manipulate your file:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=.{16}).*(?=-)//g' file
```

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat file 
May 28 04:28:15 apps1 docker/[a:vjwdrze2e3qxrf5eck4s3yv:a][u:jack:u][5425]: 05:30:15.693 INFO  [mockAppThread:21] app.js - TEST MESSAGE 3 
May 29 01:30:15 apps1 docker/[a:vjwdrze2e3qxrf5eck4s3yv:a][u:jack:u][5425]: 05:30:15.693 INFO  [mockAppThread:21] app.js - API Mock App Server started successfully on 0.1.0.0 with port 7001.
May 30 11:30:15 apps1 docker/[a:vjwdrze2e3qxrf5eck4s3yv:a][u:jack:u][5425]: 05:30:15.693 INFO  [mockAppThread:21] app.js - TEST MESSAGE 2
```

**OUPUT:**

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=.{16}).*(?=-)//g' file                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
May 28 04:28:15 - TEST MESSAGE 3 
May 29 01:30:15 - API Mock App Server started successfully on 0.1.0.0 with port 7001.
May 30 11:30:15 - TEST MESSAGE 2
```

**Explanations:**

This `perl` command will delete the string starting at the 17th position until the reaching the `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the recurrent strucutre (keyword). A sed solution

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9]\{2\}\).*\(- API\)/\1 \2/' YourFile
```